# Solving the infinite sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi}^{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sin x\right)}{x^{2}}\right)dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, summation, recreational-mathematics

I came upon this problem while messing around with the function $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sin x\right)}{x^{2}}\right)$ (Hence the recreational mathematics tag)

I noticed that the function's domain was $2n\pi<x<(2n+1)\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I also noticed the integral $\int_{2n\pi}^{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sin x\right)}{x^{2}}\right)dx$ converges for all $n$ (as we have previously defined $n$ as any integer). I saw that as $n$ approached $-\infty$ and $\infty$, the integral approached $0$.

I then had an interesting idea: to sum the integrals for all $n$. That is how I got to the infinite sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi}^{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sin x\right)}{x^{2}}\right)dx$.

Using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qxgbqulv2s), I approximated it to $−1.46193837522$ with summation bounds $-155$ and $134$.

I do not even know how to begin solving this problem but my assumption would be to find an indefinite integral first.

I am looking for a closed form which may or may not exist.

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't say you have "no idea." You've noticed that the integrand is supposedly integrable on any $[2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi]$ and that the areas might approach 0 as $n \to \infty$ and as $n \to -\infty$. Not that I know an efficient method, but since there doesn't seem to be an antiderivative, you could try evaluating $\int_{2n\pi}^{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sin x\right)}{x^{2}}\right)dx$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ instead of an indefinite integral, and then try to evaluate the series after. Just throwing in my two cents.

Comment: This is a pretty 'random' function. I will be astonished if this series has a closed form

Comment: More precisely $-1.46270300698980141711004206736396724376663425156\dots$

Comment: @metamorphy. Pari/GP ?

Comment: @Claude: yes, of course ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Abandon hope all ye who enter here"* as wrote Dante Alighieri in *"The Divine Comedy"*.

The summation converges very slowly. Consider
$$S_p=\sum_{n=-100p}^{n=+100p} J_n\qquad \text{where} \qquad J_n=\int_{2n\pi}^{\left(2n+1\right)\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\log\left(\sin (x)\right)}{x^{2}}\right)\,dx$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 1 & -1.461605315 \\
 2 & -1.462152793 \\
 3 & -1.462335893 \\
 4 & -1.462427557 \\
 5 & -1.462482592 \\
 6 & -1.462519297 \\
 7 & -1.462545523 \\
 8 & -1.462565196 \\
 9 & -1.462580500 \\
 10 & -1.462592744 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

which *seems* to converge to some $-1.4627030$ which is not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.